# How would the term golden shaft be translated in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, ancient-greek, mythology

There is a epithet for the greek goddess Artemis, Khryselakatos (Χρυσηλάκατος), which means "of the Golden Shaft." How would one translate that into Latin? The closest I can determine would be *auraus harundinēs*, but my knowledge of ancient Latin is limited. Is this correct? Is there a more accurate term? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [q.v.](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*x%3Aentry+group%3D39%3Aentry%3Dxrushla%2Fkatos)

Comment: On the other hand, some translate Hom Il 20.70: Ἥρῃ δ᾽ ἀντέστη χρυσηλάκατος κελαδεινὴ Ἄρτεμις ἰοχέαιρα κασιγνήτη ἑκάτοιο as  "the archer-goddess Artemis with her golden arrows, sister of far-darting Apollo, stood to face Hera". Have you tried a Latin translation of the Iliad?

Comment: A ἠλακάτη is specifically and unambiguously a distaff, but the arrow interpretation is due to the scholia; the Souda glosses χρυσηλάκατος as 'ἡ καλλίτοξος, ἡ χρυσότοξος'.

Comment: The word *harundo* is a somewhat technical term that does not normally appear in poetic contexts, at least that I have seen. Normally classical authors refer to arrows as *sagittae* or generically as *tela*. However, as Cosmas points out, that epithet refers to her distaff, not to her arrows, so the whole question is moot.